# implicit declaration of function free is invalid in c99

Tags: c, xcode

In xcode 5 I get this warning:

> "implicit declaration of function free is invalid in c99"

How should I free my c structures if I can't use the function free()?

Comment: Did you include `<stdlib.h>` ?

Comment: Did you declare the memory for the structure using malloc or calloc functions?

Comment: @ Michael : I have the same error, and tried to include `<stdlib.h>` but the error not disappear

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) function is declared in the `<stdlib.h>` header file.

Comment: This is a terrible answer, if I may say so...

Comment: Perhaps a *little* better now.

Answer (score 9):

You get that warning because you're calling a function without first declaring it, so the compiler doesn't know about the function.

All functions need to be declared before being called, there are no "built-in" functions in C.

It's true that `free()` is a function defined in the standard, but it's still not built-in, you must have a prototype for it.

To figure out which header has the prototype, try searching for "man free" and look for a [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free). Close to the top, it says:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *malloc(size_t size);
void free(void *ptr);
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

This tells you that in order to use the listed functions, you should add:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to your source code.